# How to speed up script execution?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

Some of my JavaScript components are loading rather slowly, so to narrow down the problem, I came up with this code:

```
<div id="react-root">Loading...</div>
<script>document.getElementById('react-root').innerHTML = 'done!';</script>
```

It turns out that even this is slow! The "Loading..." text stays on the page for about half a second before being overwritten (not sure how to time that more accurately).

However, the [same code on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vucovigoki/1/edit?html,output) runs so fast that I can't see the "Loading" text.

So my question is, what could cause the execution of a script to be delayed?

I *do* have about <del>a megabyte</del> 244 KB of compressed+gzipped JS on the page, so there are a lot of things that could cause slowness, but there's no other code between those two lines, so I don't know how something would interfere.

---

The rest of the assets are loaded like this in the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><script src="/assets/ie8-c0c685babae124215518.js" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/assets/main-c0c685babae124215518.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="/assets/main-a1c8b4b15e068ad0290ba74f8ec0bc51.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Removing them *does* speed up the execution of that little loader script. However, I can't simply remove them nor make them async because then my app won't work. Is there something specific I should be looking for in that JS? Or does having one block of JS just slow down all other `<script>`s on the page, or what?

Comment: Where is this megabyte of JavaScript code in relation to the lines above? And how it is loaded? `script` tags with inline content? `script` tags referencing external files? If so, with or without `async` and/or `defer`? What browser(s) do you see the behavior in? Have you tried others to bracket the problem?

Comment: @StevenMays It is an external script, and it's permanently cached. Chrome says "(from Cache)" so it doesn't even make a network request.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Specifically, it's loaded with `<script src="/assets/main-c0c685babae124215518.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` in the `<head>`. I don't think I can make it async without breaking the app; it's a very old app.

Comment: Okay, so that code's already been parsed by the time you get to the stuff in your question. (I suggest updating the question to show that relationship, so it's not hidden in a comment.)

Comment: @mpen in your JSBin I'm not seeing the javascript.... can you make sure it's in there and the link is posted correctly.

Comment: @StevenMays: By "the same code" I believe he's talking about the code in the question, not the megabyte of code linked to the page. It's in the HTML of the JSBin.

Comment: What happens if you **only** have the big script and the above in the page? E.g., literally `<doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><script src="the-big-script.js"></script></head><body><div>...</div><script>/*update the div*/</script></body></html>`?

Comment: @StevenMays I'm talking about the 1 line script in the "HTML" section of the JSbin. I can't throw the meg of JS up on JSbin. It's a big compressed mess anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see a white page for a short while, and then "done". The "Loading" text never appears. I imagine it's blocking for awhile while the big script is doing whatever, and then as soon as that's done the rest of the page loads instantly.

Comment: You should at least be able to move the scripts from the head into the body, after the loading indicator.

Comment: How are that JS and CSS file created?

Comment: @Bergi Maybe. Most pages don't actually have loaders, it's just some of the newer pages that we're moving to JS. The issue isn't really whether or not the loader shows before the page hangs though, I just wanted to decrease the amount of time between when the header/footer show and the main content.

Comment: @robertklep Webpack.

Comment: A mb of Js is 10 times the size of jquery. Are you sure about the numbers?

Comment: @EdHeal Uhh...in production mode the main bundle comes down to 244 KB gzipped, 841 KB not gzipped. Every page includes the main bundle, but most pages have a few additional scripts. The additional scripts are loaded asynchronously, however.

Comment: Jquery from here is 84k https://jquery.com/download/ I have just checked

Comment: @EdHeal Yeow..is it that big? We do include jQuery, so that's probably a large percentage of our bundle then :P

Comment: 84k is under 10% of 1 mb. Have you wrote 9 times more code for one page considering jqery makes  it generic for all browsers.

Comment: @EdHeal If you're really curious, here's all the junk we include: http://pastebin.com/r7ASaU8D

Comment: I ran the HTML script locally and there was no "loading" process. It just came up with the done indicating very fast script execution. In order to look into this further please post the JSBin with all materials.

Comment: No matter what it's got to parse that JavaScript, even if it's already in the cache. It's going to be nigh on impossible to answer this question without knowing what's in that script. Even then... that's a lot of code to ask SO volunteers to go through.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Right, which is one of the reasons I don't really want to post it. I don't expect anyone to sift through that :-) Was just hoping someone could suggest a couple reasons for a delay between a `<div>` and a `<script>`. I thought the browser would parse that sequentially -- so as soon as the div rendered, the `<script>` on the next line would execute pretty much immediately thereafter. I didn't think another script on the page could possibly slow that down, because by the time it got to that `<div>` the big script should already have been parsed.